# Python scraping web page causes javascript issue

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, urllib2

I am using urllib2 to scrape a webpage. It works well on a lot of sites, but in some, I get:

```
<html><title>You are being redirected...</title>
<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>
```

Here's my code:

```
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

    req = urllib2.Request(url=link, headers=hdr)
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        return None
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        return None
    mycontent = f.read()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mind posting the url your trying to scrape?

Comment: @BOi - just edited to add an example link.

Comment: Try using `requests`, it will follow the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a javascript issue, pay attention to the first line:

```
<html><title>You are being redirected...</title>
```

This means you have to follow the redirection until you reach the destination server.

`urllib2.urlopen` does not do that automatically, you need to call `.geturl()` on the result, or use other functions or libraries, that resolve redirects.